# Чат на java (android)

Tags: java, android, сокет, чат

Добрый день!
Нашел достаточно "простой" и качественно оформленный [пример](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/) чата на java.
Но вот проблема, познания в сетях свехр минимальны, и я не могу понять к какому ip адресу нужно пытаться подключаться (экспериментирую на 2х эмуляторах, которые на ноуте, он в сети по WIFI и телефоне он в сети по WIFI и 3G (WIFI общий)).
В серверной части добавил такой код

```
try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            List<InetAddress> addresses = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress add2 : addresses) {
                string = add2.getHostAddress();                    
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

и получил ip устройства, где запущена серверная часть 
::1%1
127.0.0.1
fe80::a00:27ff:fe50:2f43%eth1
10.0.3.15
fe80::a00:27ff:fec3:8b61%eth0
192.168.56.102

Далее ход мысли следующий:
127.0.0.1 - он же localhost - использовать нет смысла, т.к. используя на клиентской части localhost буду обращаться сам на себя

192.168.56.102 и 10.0.3.15 если правильно понимаю 192 и 10 это подсети локальной сети (т.е. WIFI) и наверно как минимум находясь в одной WIFI сети должна сработать попытка соединения на один из этих ip

Прошелся в режиме Debug по коду Client.java и обнаружил в части кода

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Получаю exception java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to 192.168.56.102 (port 8090): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Порты пробовал менять, без результатно

И что интересно переменная **socket** равно **null**, мне почему-то кажется, что не зависимо от того какой ip адрес использую в `socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);`
**socket  не должна быть null**

Пока есть два предположения 
1 - либо нужно как-то использовать ip6 полученные вместе с ip4 fe80::a00:27ff:fe50:2f43%eth1, fe80::a00:27ff:fec3:8b61%eth0
2 - брандмауэр на ПК блокирует запросы

Первое предположение подтвердилось, для клиентской части указал ip6 полученный на серверной части, сообщения стали проходить, но только в режиме эмулятор-эмулятор. Сообщения между эмулятор-телефон не проходят.

Что нужно для того чтобы сообщения проходили в любом направлении, а еще более актуально, что нужно чтобы был возможен обмен сообщениями для нескольких телефонов использующих 3G либо WIFI разных точек доступа?

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит начать с чего-то по проще чем чат. Например, разобраться с тем как работает сервер и что такое locahost.

Comment: у вас сокет не создается, поскольку конструктор выкидывает исключение, поскольку подключиться к 192.168.56.102:8090 не удалось. Поэтому он `null`. 192.168.56.102 - это вообще кто?

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вашего сервера вообще есть видимый вам адрес? Другими способами можете это проверить?

Comment: телефон как связан с "серверной частью"? Общий wifi?

Comment: проблема в том, что абсолютно не уверен. не до конца понимаю, как вообще определяется что нужно подключаться на такой-то ip.
может вообще нужно у провайдера покупать белый ip и на том ПК, запускать серверную часть? хотя опять же есть роутер и он явно вносит свои корректировки в адресацию.

Есть желание разобраться с работой сети и сокетами в частности, но пока только грабли, которые не понимаю как обойти и с какой стороны подступиться, то что гуглю, пока не наводит на прояснение вопроса.